# Eloquent laravel 6

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estuve buscando la forma de hacer esta consulta con eloquent de laravel

```
SELECT * FROM `procedures` WHERE `service_id` = 1 AND (`sex` = 'male' OR `sex` = 'all')
```

No encontré así que solo por continuar con mis practicas lo hice de esta manera

```
\DB::SELECT("SELECT * FROM procedures WHERE service_id = $id AND (sex = 'male' OR sex = 'all')");
```

He intentado algunos métodos de la documentación pero no he podido dar con la solución

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas Eloquent y tienes el modelo Procedure correspondiente, podrías hacer algo así:

```
Procedure::whereServiceId($id)
         ->where(function($q) {
             $q->where('sex', 'male')
               ->orWhere('sex', 'all');
         })->get();
```

En caso que no tengas el modelo, puedes hacerlo con el query Builder:

```
\DB::table('procedures')
   ...
```